# Adding a scoreboard to an android studio application

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a score board to my android activity but I can't find anything useful online. I can't use googles leaderboard as I have to present my app to someone who will be downloading the code and running it not the published app. The person I'm doing the app with sent me this code but it's not working. If anybody has any good links on how to make a score boards from scratch or could tell me what's wrong with this code i'd appreciate it

```
public class Leaderboard extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView UsernameList;
    private ListView ScoreList;

    /** Called when the activity is first created */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
        ArrayAdapter<Integer> list2Adapter;

        //Find the ListView resources
        UsernameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.UsernameList);
        ScoreList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ScoreList);

        //Create and populate the list of usernames.
        //This is where the information from the Database would need to be entered. and the String[] removed
        String[] usernames = new String[]{"Andy", "Marie", "George"};
        ArrayList<String> usernameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        usernameList.addAll(Arrays.asList(usernames));

        //Create and populate the list of scores
        //This is where the information from the Database would need to be entered. and the Integer[] removed
        Integer[] scores = new Integer[]{7, 4, 1};
        ArrayList<Integer> scoreList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        scoreList.addAll(Arrays.asList(scores));

        //Create Array Adapter using the username list
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_row, usernameList);
        //Add more users
        listAdapter.add("Michael");
        //Set the Array Adapter as the ListView's adapter
        UsernameList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        //Create Array Adapter using the username list
        list2Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.activity_row, scoreList);
        //Add more users
        list2Adapter.add(0);
        //Set the Array Adapter as the ListView's adapter
        ScoreList.setAdapter(list2Adapter);

    }
}
```

(This is the java class of the leaderboard that was sent to me)

Comment: offcource its not working. you need the xml files that go with the code (UsernameList, ScoreList, activity_row)

Comment: I know, I have the xml files set up. I just didn't think there was any need to post them here.

Comment: ill do a demo for you that populates the scoreboard list from a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set the view of the activity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a demo i created, using an sqllite database to read the names and scores

I called it Scoreboard

**Main Activity code**

```
package com.scroreboard.live.scoreboard;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.scroreboard.live.scoreboard.adapter.CustomListAdapter;
import com.scroreboard.live.scoreboard.model.Items;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Items> itemsList = new ArrayList<Items>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;

        try {

            //Create a Database if doesnt exist otherwise Open It

            myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("leaderboard", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            //Create table in database if it doesnt exist allready

            myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (name TEXT, score TEXT);");

            //Select all rows from the table

            Cursor cursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM scores", null);

            //If there are no rows (data) then insert some in the table

            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {

                    myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO scores (name, score) VALUES ('Andy', '7');");
                    myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO scores (name, score) VALUES ('Marie', '4');");
                    myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO scores (name, score) VALUES ('George', '1');");

                }

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {

            //Initialize and create a new adapter with layout named list found in activity_main layout

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, itemsList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            Cursor cursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM scores", null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                    //read all rows from the database and add to the Items array

                    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                        Items items = new Items();

                        items.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                        items.setScore(cursor.getString(1));

                        itemsList.add(items);
                        cursor.moveToNext();


                    }
                }

            //All done, so notify the adapter to populate the list using the Items Array

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }
```

In your project right click on (in my case) **com.scroreboard.live.scoreboard** and select **new --> package** like you see in the picture

Create 2 packages one called **adapter** and another **model**

[image]

right Click on **adapter** and select **new --> Java Class**

name it **CustomListAdapter**

right Click on **model** and select **new --> Java Class**

name it **Items**

**CustomListAdapter code**

```
package com.scroreboard.live.scoreboard.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.scroreboard.live.scoreboard.R;
import com.scroreboard.live.scoreboard.model.Items;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private  Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Items> itemsItems;



    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<Items> itemsItems) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.itemsItems = itemsItems;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return itemsItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View scoreView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (inflater == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        if (scoreView == null) {

            scoreView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) scoreView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.score = (TextView) scoreView.findViewById(R.id.score);

            scoreView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) scoreView.getTag();
        }

        final Items m = itemsItems.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(m.getName());
        holder.score.setText(m.getScore());

        return scoreView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView name;
        TextView score;

    }

}
```

**Items Code**

```
package com.scroreboard.live.scoreboard.model;

public class Items {

    private String name, score;

    public Items() {
    }

    public Items(String name, String score) {

        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

Couple of more things.

In the`main_activity` layout file or whatever activity layout you want to add a ListView add the below (Style it as you wish)

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"/>
```

lastly create another layout resource and call it **list_row**

**XML code that goes inside it**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#222222"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="#222222"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Ok all done, and should be self explanatory

Complete App structure

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I just copied it. But while mentioning text size use sp instead of dp